# LINQ to change KeyValuePair in dict

Tags: c#, regex, linq, dictionary

I'm attempting to use Regex to parse through an input text of a chemical formula. The Regex should be able to handle multiples of the same element ie CH4 or CHHHH.

For my other dictionarys, I've used if(Dict.ContainsKey(H) Dict[H].Value++;

```
        int count = 0;

        string chemForm = tbxFormula.Text.ToString();

        string pat = @"(?<Key>[A-Z]|([A-Z][a-z]))(?<Value>[0-9]|() )";


        KVPs = (from Match m in Regex.Matches(chemForm, pat)
                select new
                {
                    key = m.Groups["Key"].Value,
                    value = int.Parse(m.Groups["Value"].Value) ,

                }).ToDictionary(p => p.key, p => p.value);
```

Error: The input string was not formatted correctly. Or "key already exists in dictionary".

Comment: you need to make sure that there is no duplicate in your keys. a key is unique and it cannot exist more than once

Comment: You could do a `GroupBy` before the `ToDictionary` to group on the keys and aggregate the values.

Answer (score 0):

```
try this:

 //string chemForm = "HHO"; // H2 O1
 string chemForm = "CH4N10"; // C1 H4 N10
 var distinctElements = new HashSet<char>();
 var KVPs = new Dictionary<char, int>();

chemForm
.ToUpper()
.ToCharArray()
.Where(c => Regex.Match(c.ToString(), @"[A-Z]").Success)
.ToList()
.ForEach(c => distinctElements.Add(c));

foreach (char c in distinctElements)
{
   Match m = Regex.Match(chemForm,
   $@"(?<element>[{c}]+(?=\D|\b))|(?<quantifiedElement>[{c}][0-9]+)");
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(m.Groups["element"].Value)) KVPs.Add(c, 
   m.Groups["element"].Value.Length);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(m.Groups["quantifiedElement"].Value)) KVPs.Add(c, 
  int.Parse(m.Groups["quantifiedElement"].Value.Substring(1)));
}

KVPs.Dump();
```